# How to implement the field decimal(5,2) in EntityFrameworkCore 1.0 rc2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to implement the field `decimal(5,2)` in `EntityFrameworkCore 1.0 rc2` ?

`HasPrecision` seems to be not available anymore?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm seeing some examples like this:

```
 entityBuilder.Property(r => r.TotalScore)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(5,2)")
            .IsRequired(true);
```

and the code to support this is here, so hopefully this is supported in the version you're using:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/f416dd9a71a5a6a69715b4ba40a37e6f9da751ef/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Metadata/Internal/RelationalPropertyBuilderAnnotations.cs

Comment: Since EFCore 5, the HasPrecision property is back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635899/18097

Answer (score 41):

You can add extensions for that like this:

```
public static class SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static PropertyBuilder<decimal?> HasPrecision(this PropertyBuilder<decimal?> builder, int precision, int scale)
    {
        return builder.HasColumnType($"decimal({precision},{scale})");
    }

    public static PropertyBuilder<decimal> HasPrecision(this PropertyBuilder<decimal> builder, int precision, int scale)
    {
        return builder.HasColumnType($"decimal({precision},{scale})");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Since EF Core 5 you can use this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().Property(b => b.Amount).HasPrecision(5, 2);`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess I should have used the same values, I came across this question and just posted what I was using. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 18):

JFYI, if somedoby is stil comming to this question (like I did)

In the current version of EF Core (2.2) there is also the Data Annotation way to do this:

```
public class SomeEFModelClass
{
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5,2)")]
    public decimal TotalScore{ get; set; }
}
```

Link to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/data-types

Comment: Since EF Core 5 the "HasPrecision" property is back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635899/18097